# adding CDATA tag to incomig XMLelement

Tags: xslt

I have this below incoming SOAP message. I need to add CDATA tag for one of the complex element called "`<Ser>`". using the below xslt but it is not working.
please let me know what is the issue in the xslt.
Incoming SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:AccDetail>  
      <Ser>   
      <Ser>      
      </acc:AccDetail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://example.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:AccDetail>  
      <![CDATA[<Ser>   
      <Ser>]]>   
      </acc:AccDetail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using this below XSLT but it is not working .
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
  xmlns:acc="http://example.com"
  extension-element-prefixes="dp"
>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="ser"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ser">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <dp:serialize omit-xml-decl="yes" select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your input XML is malformed.  You have a second `<Ser>` start tag where I suppose you probably meant to have a `</Ser>` end tag.

Comment: Do you specifically need the XML for the `<Ser>` element to be embedded in a CDATA section, or would it suffice simply to escape the XML to present it as text?  Do you need the CDATA section contents to be limited to just the  text representation of one `<Ser>` element, or would it be ok if surrounding text (maybe whitespace) were included, too?  Do you need accommodate multiple `<Ser>` elements in the same parent element?  If so, do they need to be in separate CDATA sections?  Can you rely on the output to be re-parsed, or might the result tree be used directly?

Comment: Hi John, Yes that a type it should be </ser>. Yes i need all elements for complex type <ser> needs to be wrapped inside CDATA. and also top level element of <ser> is not constant it can have anything.